# main method in eclipse convention

Tags: eclipse, package, program-entry-point

I've noticed that if I put number of files into one package into a single project in Eclipse, while each file has it's own main method- the run time environment won't throw an error.

As I know each project should have only one main method.
or is it OK to have few main methods for a project- in this case what is the best way to place the main methods?

Comment: It's ok, Eclipse will ask you which "main" do you want to launch when you click "run"

Comment: You can have multiple main methods in a project. How you organise them is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many main methods as you like, the compiler or runtime won't care.  As far as a best practice goes I would lean towards a single main method for clarity.  During development I might add a main to a class for standalone testing purposes but then remove the method before delivering the change.